# Is the orthogonal group $O_n(\mathbb{R})$ isomorphic to $SO_n(\mathbb{R}) \times \{ \pm 1 \}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, orthogonality, group-isomorphism

Is the orthogonal group $O_n(\mathbb{R})$ isomorphic to $SO_n(\mathbb{R}) \times \{ \pm 1 \}$?

Here, $SO_n(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of orthogonal matrices with determinant $1$.

Comment: What element of $O_n(\mathbb R)$ do you think should play the role of $(1, -1)$? Hint: the answer depends on whether $n$ is even or odd.

Comment: I was thinking about their centers... If I prove that they have different centers then it disproves the isomorphism?

Answer (score 5):

As in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1532628/isomorphism-between-sl2-mathbbz-times-mathbbz-2-and-gl2-mathbbz/1532638#1532638), there is a short exact sequence

$$1 \to SO(n) \to O(n) \xrightarrow{\det} \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 1$$

which splits, allowing us to write $O(n)$ as a semidirect product $SO(n) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$. This semidirect product is nontrivial when $n$ is even (because there is no splitting $\mathbb{Z}_2 \to O(n)$ whose image commutes with $SO(n)$) but trivial when $n$ is odd, with the splitting given by sending $-1 \in \mathbb{Z}_2$ to $-1 \in O(n)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but we haven't learned "semidirect product" in class yet... Is there any other way that could figure it out?

Comment: I was thinking of the centers... Can I show that they have different centers to disprove isomorphism?

Comment: @selfstudy: I think this works (when $n$ is even), but I haven't checked the details.