# understanding $O(n)$ homeomorphic to $SO(n)\times \Bbb Z_2$ proof

Tags: general-topology

I am doing Exercise 4-16 in Armstrong's Basic Topology.

The question is to prove $O(n)$ homeomorphic to $SO(n)\times \Bbb Z_2$. I have some idea on how to approach this, but when I see [other people's solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1468198/two-topological-groups-mathrmon-orthogonal-group-and-mathrmson-ti) online I was very confused.

The comment suggested a function $$f:O(n)\to SO(n)\times \Bbb Z_2; f(A)=(\det(A)A, \det(A))$$
and claimed that it was a one-one, onto map. I also see this on some greg grant's solution material. But isn't $O(n)$ set of orthogonal matrices, implying the determinant of its element being $\pm1$? How could it map to anything $(..,0)$, then how is it onto?

I understand I can easily map between $\{0,1\}$ and $\{-1, 1\}$. But since it wrote $\Bbb Z_2$, I was wondering if there is some notation or basic things I am not aware of .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You understood everything correctly. It is common practice to identify $\{ \pm 1\}$ with $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: (In particular, by letting the group operation be multiplication.)

Comment: Ahh, good to know. Thank you both!

Comment: The map is not well-defined if $n$ is even. You need to replace $\det{A}$ in the first coordinate with “a fixed orthogonal matrix with determinant $\det{A}$”.

Comment: A related question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1532628/360262